# Why is the CSS hover not working?

Tags: css, wordpress

My site is test06.menchasha.ru. I am trying to apply a hover effect. A div in the right should appear when the link, 'Promotional Activities' is hovered. 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48DZG.png)

I used the following code:

```css
.child1 {
display: none;
}


a .title1:hover + .child1 {
display: inline-block;
}
```

But the hover effect is not working. What should I correct? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should first share your HTML

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question** itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the code in your link - you simply can't achieve the effect you need with your structure and only with CSS.

Here is your code:

```
a .title1:hover + .child1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want it to work the way you need your `a` element must have 2 children: `.title1` and `.child1`, also `.child1` must be direct sibling of `.title1` cause `+` selector helps you to access only the nearest sibling of the element. But in your structure all the `.child` elements are not siblings of `.title` elements, they are in another `div` block. So just use JS to make them visible on hover.